# How do I host an SSL static site using S3 and Namecheap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, amazon-cloudfront, jamstack

Note: sitenamehere is not the name of the site. Redacted it for personal reasons.

I've got a static site sitting at http://www.[sitenamehere].site.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ -- it's working fine, publicly accessible.

I want to make it available via sitenamehere.site and www.sitenamehere.site (where the first redirects to the 2nd). My understanding is that I will need 3 things to get this to work:

1. A cert via AWS cert manager (verified via DNS records)
2. A Cloudfront distribution that points to an S3 bucket
3. An S3 bucket that has publicly accessible html
4. Updated DNS records on Namecheap

It seems to me that I have all 3. But when I go to the site I get `www.sitenamehere.site’s server IP address could not be found.`

In namecheap's DNS panel I have a CNAME record:

Type: CNAME

Host: `_5ee8b630d994d9efexxxxxxxxxxxx` - (the original value was `_5ee8b630d994d9efexxxxxxxxxxxx.sitenamehere.site` but Namecheap support told me to only use the first portion)

Value: `_4998f8b754e7f59ce4d6xxxxxxxxxxxx.mzlfeqexyx.acm-validations.aws.`

ACM says the cert is validated (Validation Status: Success)

Next up: Cloudfront. I have one distribution and its Origin Domain Name is `www.sitenamehere.site.s3.amazonaws.com`. That value was available in a drop down when editing the Origin (Edit Origin screen). Origin ID: `S3-www.sitenamehere.site` Restrict Bucket Access is No. This all seems correct to me.

Next up: S3. I have a few buckets on here but the one I'm targeting is called `www.sitenamehere.site`. That's the one that I have the Cloudfront dist pointed at. It's fully public and has

```
 "Principal": "*",
 "Action": "s3:GetObject",
```

in its bucket policy.

This all looks like it should be working but it's not. What's missing?

Comment: In your namecheap DNS you need another CNAME entry for www. That www CNAME should be aliased to your CloudFront distributions address, which will be something like abcdefghijkl.cloudfront.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do two more things.

- Add Alternate Domain Names

  - Goto your CloudFront distribution settings, click "Edit"
  - under the alternate domain names, enter your website address `www.sitenamehere.site`
- In your namcheap, point the cname `www` to your cloudfront address for e.g `a1cddfe@cloudfront.net`